# Add constants issues Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got a class for storing constants.

So, there are two files that call Constant.h and Constant.m

This is what I have in .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

enum kParams {
    kFirstName = 0,
    kLastName = 1
};

extern NSString * const kNotificationUpdateMainMenu;
```

This is what I have in .m file:

```
#import "Constants.h"

NSString * const kNotificationUpdateMainMenu = @"kNotificationUpdateMainMenu";
```

For first time it works good, but when I try to add some other const (kNotificationFbLoginSuccsess for example) other classes don't see it.

This is a message that shows me which problem I have. But I don't understand how my other constants work without this issue (just new constant that I add get this error).

```
/Users/developer/Documents/Projects/Test/Test/Test/AppDelegate.m:121:64: Use of undeclared identifier 'kNotificationFbLoginSuccsess'
```

I found some way how to fix it:

- Open organizer
- Clear derived data
- Delete project.xcworkspace file and xcuserdata
- Close Project
- Relaunch Xcode

but as I think is too much operations that I can add one constant. How come?

Comment: we're doing this a bit different. We're using #define marcos and just a .h file (just a header) - works very smooth.

Comment: yes define macros is very good, but it don't solve problem with data type (for example if I use string or int or something else). And in my case all extern constants work good, but when I try to add more cost I got this error. But I'm wondering because other const work good and the Xcode parser sees it without any issues.

Comment: Did you mean to spell 'Success' as 'Succsess'?  Might be your problem?

Comment: yes, this is a mistake, but I have for example kNotificationFbLoginSuccssssess even that have mistake but there is not a problem, because I can give any names for variables. My problem is why parser can't work.

Comment: You know that defines work for Strings and ints, right?

Comment: of course, that's right. as i said it is not a problem use define instead extern string (int etc). problem in the parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "global" constant is not actually external (separately compiled and later linked together).  Take the easy way out and place `NSString * const kNotificationUpdateMainMenu = @"kNotificationUpdateMainMenu";` into the header file.  The method file needs nothing.

I would use `#define kNotificationUpdateMainMenu @"kNotificationUpdateMainMenu"` to perform the spell checking.  The compiler will create one shared instance of the constant string for the entire compilation.